# Copied old phone WhatsApp stickers to new phone, but WhatsApp doesn't recognize them

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I had a few hundred WhatsApp stickers on my old phone (that is still operational) now copied into my PC. The stickers weren't into categories, but added all of them to fav (don't know if this matters), but they were all in the `WhatsApp Stickers` folder without any subfolder structure.

I have copied all the sticker files to the `WhatsApp Stickers` folder of the new phone but they aren't being recognized from the WhatsApp app. I'm not using Google Drive backup because I only care for the stickers and because I try to not be too much googlelized.

Which should be my next step? Why WhatsApp isn't recognizing the new stickers?

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp doesn't just take images from the stickers folder and use them. It keeps a database of what stickers are registered, together with the emojis linked to each sticker and other metadata like the name of the stickers, the creator, the pack it belongs to and sometimes a link to the app they came from. You can use a local backup if you don't want to use Google, you can turn off Google Drive backup and then choose backup now to create a copy of WhatsApp, then move the files to your new phone and recover from the local backup.

Otherwise you may need to create a backup of WhatsApp on the new phone and modify the backup, but that's a bit too complicated of a process. I suggest if you can't move the data from the old phone to the new, you may be able to send all stickers to a friend from your old phone, have them forward them back to you on your new phone and select all the messages and add a star to them. The last option is just obtain all the stickers the same way you obtained them first, by going in the same groups or installing the same sticker apps.